# facebook share on others page from my account login by using a share button in my site

Tags: facebook

I want to share my data to facebook page but not on my timeline, i want to share on other page from my website.
For example i am sharing from my site by login to my account but want to share on different page.

Is this possible to do this in facebook share button?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

You can use the Share Dialog instead, it offers an option to share elsewhere:

> The Share dialog gives people the ability to publish an individual
>   story to their timeline, a friend's timeline, a group, or in a private
>   message on Messenger.

You can also use sharer.php for this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[encoded-url]
```

**Afaik it´s not possible to post to a Page you don´t manage.**

Comment: no actually i want to share on my liked page ,but there is no option for that. It gives only option share on friends timeline,share with group,share in an event and share to newsfeed.

Comment: ok, that´s not possible afaik, you can only share to your own timeline, a friend timeline, a group, or a page you manage. or event (did not know about that).